# order analysis of recurrence relation

Tags: numerical-methods, algorithms, recurrence-relations, dynamical-systems

Given a fixed $\eta > 0$, consider the recurrence relation

$$
x_1 = 0 
\quad \text{and} \quad
x_{t+1} = x_t + \eta \cdot \frac{2}{(1+x_t)^2}
\enspace.
$$

**Question**: How can we establish that the recurrence satisfies $x_t = \mathcal{\Theta} \left( ( \eta \cdot t )^{1/3} \right)$ ?

I am looking for an approach that provides *explicit constants* here.

Here's my attempt so far:
I have conducted some simulations to verify that

$$
\left[ ( 6 t \cdot \eta + 1 )^{1/3} - 1 \right] 
\leq x_t 
\leq C(\eta) \cdot \left[ ( 6 t \cdot \eta + 1 )^{1/3} - 1 \right] 
\enspace,
$$

where $C(\eta)$ is a constant which depends on the fixed $\eta$.
I obtained the guess of $( 6 t \cdot \eta + 1 )^{1/3} - 1$ by viewing the recurrence relation as the Euler discretization of the differential equation $\frac{\partial}{\partial s} x(s) = \frac{2}{(1 + x(s))}$ and $x(0) = 0$ with step size $\eta > 0$.
But, the above inequality was obtained only through simulations and I don't have a formal proof.
Here is some progress on obtaining a slightly weaker lower bound.

**Proposition**: The recurrence is lower bounded as $x_t \geq \left( 6 (t-1) \cdot \eta + 1 \right)^{1/3} - 1$.

**Proof**:
Define $R_t = \frac{1}{\eta} \left( \left( x_t + 1 \right)^3 - 1\right)$.
It suffices to show that $R_t \geq 6 (t-1)$.
To this end, observe that

\begin{align*}
R_t &= \sum_{s=1}^{t-1} \left( R_{s+1} - R_s \right) + R_1 &\text{(telescoping)} \\
&= \sum_{s=1}^{t-1} \left( R_{s+1} - R_s \right) &\text{($R_1 = 0$)} \\
&= \frac{1}{\eta} \sum_{s=1}^{t-1} \left( x_{s+1} + 1 \right)^3 - \left( x_s + 1 \right)^3 &\text{(def of $R_t$)} \\
&= \frac{1}{\eta} \sum_{s=1}^{t-1} \left( x_{s} + 1 + \eta \frac{2}{(1+x_s)^2} \right)^3 - \left( x_s + 1 \right)^3 &\text{(recurrence)} \\
&= \frac{1}{\eta} \sum_{s=1}^{t-1} \left[ 3 (x_s +1)^2 \cdot \left( \frac{2 \eta}{(1 + x_s)^2} \right) + 3 (x_s +1) \left( \frac{2 \eta}{(1+x_s)^2} \right)^2 + \left( \frac{2 \eta}{(1+x_s)^2} \right)^{3}  \right] &\text{(expansion)}\\
&= \sum_{s=1}^{t-1} \left[ 6 + \frac{12 \eta}{(1+x_s)^3} + \frac{8 \eta^2}{(1+x_s)^6} \right] \\
&\geq 6 (t-1) \enspace.
\end{align*}

But, I'm still stuck on proving an upper bound on the recurrence relation.
I think it can be helpful to define the $R_t$ and consider a telescoping sum, but I'm not sure how to gracefully upper bound the other two terms that appear there.

Answer (score 2):

First, you can see that the sequence is non-increasing, since $x_{t+1}-x_t\geq 0$.
Then two possibilities: Either it is bounded from above, or it's not. In the former case, it would have to converge to a limit $l$. That limit would have to verify $$l = l + \eta \cdot \frac{2}{(1+x_t)^2}$$
which has no solution. Thus the sequence diverges to infinity: $x_t\rightarrow+\infty$.

For convenience, define $y_t=\frac 1 {x_t}$. Then that sequence also verifies a recurrence relation:
$$
y_{t+1} = \frac 1 { x_t + \eta \cdot \frac{2}{(1+x_t)^2}}=\frac 1 {x_t}\cdot\frac 1 {1+\eta\cdot\frac 2 {x_t^3(1+\frac 1 {x_t})^2}}=y_t\cdot\frac 1 {1+\eta\cdot y_t^3\frac 2 {(1+y_t)^2}}
$$
Now consider $\alpha\in \mathbb R-\{0\}$. Since $y_t\rightarrow 0$, you can compute a Taylor expansion of $y_t^\alpha$ as $t\rightarrow+\infty$:
$$\begin{split}
y_{t+1}^\alpha &=y_t^\alpha\left(1+2\,\eta\, y_t^3(1+y_t)^{-2}\right)^{-\alpha}\\
&= y_t^\alpha\left(1+2\,\eta\, y_t^3(1+o(1))^{-2}\right)^{-\alpha}\\
&= y_t^\alpha\left(1+2\,\eta\, y_t^3+o(y_t^3)\right)^{-\alpha}\\
&= y_t^\alpha\left(1-2\,\alpha\,\eta \, y_t^3+o(y_t^3)\right)\\
&= y_t^\alpha -2\,\alpha\,\eta \,y_t^{\alpha+3}+o(y_t^{\alpha+3})
\end{split}$$
So if you choose $\alpha = -3$:
$$y_{t+1}^{-3}=y_t^{-3} +6\,\eta+o(1)$$
Summing this down all the way to $t=0$ gives:
$$y_t^{-3}\sim 6\,\eta\, t$$

$$\boxed{x_t \sim \left( 6\,\eta \,t\right)^{1/3}}$$

Comment: thanks for the thoughtful response! Is it possible to use this Taylor series approach to derive an upper bound on $x_t$ with explicit constants?

Comment: Yes, if you take use an explicit form for the Taylor expansion remainder, you can, in theory get that. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Explicit_formulas_for_the_remainder

Comment: Equivalently, you can write $y_{t+1}=y_t+f(y_t)$ and you find a bound for $f$ in the neighborhood of $0$. To do the latter you can bound the first and second derivatives of that function.

Answer (score 2):

Enhance the equation to
$$
1+x_{t+1}=\underbrace{(1+x_t)}_{=a}+\underbrace{\frac{2\eta}{(1+x_t)^2}}_{=b}
$$
Consider that with the cubic binomial expansion
$$
(a+b)^3=a^3+3a^2b+3ab^2+b^3
$$
and $x_t$ large, the last two terms become negligible. Anyway, as long as the terms are positive, the first two terms give the lower bound
$$
(1+x_{t+1})^3\ge (1+x_t)^3+6\eta
$$
so that in solving the recursion
$$
(1+x_t)^3\ge (1+x_0)^3+6\eta t.
$$
Insert the initial condition $x_0=0$ (or shift the index for $x_1=0$) this gives
$$
x_t\ge(1+6\eta t)^{1/3}-1,
$$
which for large values of $t$ has the claimed behavior.

Comment: thanks! However, I'm a bit confused by your answer. I don't see how the second inequality follows from the first -- in particular, "$x_t$ large" seems to be doing some work here that I don't follow. Also, I'm looking for an upper bound on $x_t$. Any thoughts in this direction?

Comment: "From first to second" is just solving the recursion, for instance as telescoping sum, $y_{n+1}\ge y_n+d$ $\implies$$y_n-y_0=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(y_{k+1}-y_k)\ge nd$. For my notation, $x_0=0$ would be a more comfortable initial condition, for yours you need to shift the index by 1. // "$x_t$ large" is only important to say that the lower bound is not too bad, that the last two terms in $(a+b)^3=a^3+3a^2b+3ab^2+b^3$, $a=1+x_t$, $b=2\eta/(1+x_t)^2$, are not important, the inequality is true in any case.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! This looks like the same proof of the lower bound in my original post, but it's better notation. Glad to see we both got the same answer :) Any thoughts on an upper bound with explicit constants?

Comment: You could insert the lower bound in the second term of the recursion equation to get something larger. It should be possible to sum this up to get an upper bound.

Comment: great point! I got this to work. Do you mind if I edit your answer to include this and then accept it?